# Yes/No : $I$ is a Principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Is  the following statement  true/false ?

> Let $I = \{ f(x)  \in  \mathbb{Z}[x]: f(1)=f(-1)=0\}$. Then $I$  is a principal ideal  of  $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

My attempt: I  thinks  this  is false  because  I  is generated by $ -1$ and $+1$ and  we  know that for  principal ideal  it  must be generated by single element.

Comment: I think you should check the definition of generators for an ideal, they have to be elements of the ideal, which $+1$ and $-1$ are not in this case, they are constant functions so when evaluated at $\pm 1$ they do not give zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $I$ is generated by $x^2-1\in \Bbb Z[x]$.

If $f\in I$ then $f$ vanishes at **both** $+1$ and $-1$. So $(x-1)$ as well as $(x+1)$ are factors of $f$. That's $f$ is divisible by $x^2-1$. Hence $I\subseteq \langle x^2-1\rangle$.

Also for any $f\in \langle x^2-1\rangle $ we have $g\in \Bbb Z[x]$ such that, $f(x)=(x^2-1)g(x)\implies f(\pm 1)=0\implies f\in I$. So $\langle x^2-1\rangle \subseteq I$.

Combining these $I=\langle x^2-1\rangle$.

Comment: here two element  are there  $(x-1) $and $(x+1)$   How  it can be principal Ideal ?

Comment: @jasmine how is $(6)$ in $\mathbb Z$ a principal ideal?

Comment: @jasmine, $f(x)=x-1$ doesn't satisfy $f(-1)=0$ so its not in the ideal. Similarly for $g(x)=x+1$, it's not in the ideal since $g(1)\neq 0$.

Comment: thanks@AndresMejia  thanks  u got